# How to override the managed version of dependencies in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot allows us to change the Java version using:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Is there any property to change the Java EE version or spring version in my Spring Boot `pom.xml`?

Currently I override the managed version using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there a better way to do this, like just setting properties?

Spring Boot 1.2.3 gives you Spring 4.1.6 by default.
How can I force Spring Boot to give me 4.1.5 instead, just by setting properties?

Answer (score 6):

This in your `pom.xml` should do it:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

All straight from the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-dependency-versions-with-maven).

Before you go overboard overriding versions of dependencies, heed this advise (from the link above):

> Each Spring Boot release is designed and tested against a specific set of third-party dependencies. Overriding versions may cause compatibility issues.

Comment: Another thing to note as I came across, *This only works if your Maven project inherits (directly or indirectly) from spring-boot-dependencies. If you have added spring-boot-dependencies in your own dependencyManagement section with <scope>import</scope> you have to redefine the artifact yourself instead of overriding the property.* (Quoted from the docs)