# Manual configuration of Hibernate with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm new into Spring and Hibernate. I've got a Spring Boot project and I want to integrate Hibernate on my own. Spring Boot tries to configure Hibernate on it's own and I want to switch it off. My project is child of spring-boot-starter-parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: @JakubKubrynski First, I can't choose version of Hibernate. Second, I'd like to configure everything in Java's Annotations, just for practise. Anyway, I'll probably just migrate to standard MVC since Spring Boot does so much for me that I can't handle it.

Comment: You can choose versions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989306/how-to-override-the-managed-version-of-dependencies-in-spring-boot/ http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-dependency-versions-with-maven / `<hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>` . When you fundamentally don't like automagical configuration, don't choose a framework that aims to provide exactly that :)

Comment: That's absolutely right.

Comment: @zapl Spring Boot provides more than Hibernate auto configuration :)

Answer (score 3):

Generally to exclude particular auto configuration in Spring Boot you just need to use annotation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class HibernateExclusionConfig {}
```

But remember that Spring Boot allows you to override single beans by simply defining your instances, for example with `@Bean` methods in `@Configuration` classes